# Search nearby users in cloud functions

Tags: function, cloud, token

I have 2 firestore collections - `users/{user}/clients` and `users/{user}/pros`. If a new client registers and a new document is created, I want to search collection `pros` for professionals working in the matching field and living within 5 km (of the new client), send notification to the pros filtered, and redirect them to a new page that shows the new client's details. In order to implement that in cloud functions,
I installed geofirestore and wrote code like this;

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document("users/{user}/clients/{client}")
.onCreate(async snapshot => {
try {
    const clientfield = snapshot.data().field;
    const clientaddress = snapshot.data().address;
    const clientgeopoint = snapshot.data().g.geopoint;
    
    const geocollection = geofirestore.collection('users/{user}/pros');
    const query = geocollection.near({center: clientgeopoint, radius: 5}).where('sector', '==', clientsector);
    const tokenArray = [];
    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let token = doc.data().fcmToken
        tokenArray.push(token);
    }) 
  }).catch ((error) => console.log(error));
    const message = {
    "notification": {
        title: 'blah',
        body: 'blah'
    },
}
return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenArray, message);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
})
```

Notification part works now, but I still have this problem of redirecting to a page that shows a new client's request details for the pros to see when they click and open the app. How can I redirect users to a page when they click the notification and open the app? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Seems like you ended up with an empty tokenArray. Did you check it, and check your query result?

Comment: Thanks for reply Don, notification part works now, but I still have this problem of making a page that shows a new client's request detail for the pros to see when they click and open the app. For that, I plan to create a new 'notifs' collection for each pros filtered as you see in the code above. Do you know how?

Comment: Your best bet is to make that a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a new question about redirecting to a page on notification click, and got the answer there. Please refer to here -> [how to redirect users to a page on notification click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597291/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-page-on-notification-click)